# Установка java 8 на windows server 2008 R2

Tags: java

Добрый вечер. Вопрос покажется простым, но у меня проблема с решением.
ОС - Windows Server 2008 R2 x64. При установке Java 8 в папке
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\Bin не появляется папка "client". Вместо неё появляется папка "server". Связано ли это с тем, что операционная система серверная, не знаю. Разработчики, поставляющие нашей организации программное обслуживание, утверждают, что вне зависимости от версии ОС, папка "client" должна появиться. Из-за этого я не могу дальше настроить ПО. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Просьба большая помочь

Comment: Нет, на Windows Server клиентский JRE не устанавливается. По крайней мере стандартным инсталлятором Oracle. Интересно, что разработчики этого не знают. Что за ПО такое, которые работает только с клиентским JRE?

Comment: Сергей, спасибо за ответ. ПО - ЦАБС 21 век Инверсия. Самое интересное следующее: я сейчас на windows 7 установил java 8 и у меня также вместо папки "client", появилась папка "server". Когда несколько лет назад на этот же сервер  поставили java 7, папка "client" была и она есть до сих пор

Comment: 64-битную версию установили?

Comment: Да. Windows server 2008 и windows 7 - обе 64 разрядные ОС

Comment: Клиентская VM была удалена из всех 64-битных версий Java HotSpot.

Comment: Самое интересное, 32 разрядная Java поставилась на 64 разрядную ОС. Чудеса. И папка "client" тоже есть

Comment: Да поставится-то она без проблем, только не сможет использовать ресурсы системы в полном объёме.

Comment: Хотя бы так. Спасибо за разъяснения!!!